# Blade If Statement

Tags: php, laravel

In  Laravel I want to run more checks across my navigation blade, for this I added a public variable and use a check inside of blade template. Is this correct?

**Main Controller**

```
    protected $isHome = 0;


    public function showHome()
    {
        $this->isHome = 1;
        return View::make('login');
    }
```

**Blade Template**

```
    @if($this->isHome = 0))
        <p> this is not home </p>
    @endif
```

This doest not seem to work any ideas?

Comment: on your Blade template, it should not be `@if($this->isHome = 0))`, rather `@if($this->isHome == 0)`

Answer (score 3):

In your template code, be sure to use two equal signs, i.e. `==` and not just `=`. The latter assigns a value to the variable, instead of *checking* the variable against a value.

The following should work better:

```
@if($this->isHome == 0)
    <p> this is not home </p>
@endif
```

[Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures)

Comment: Double equals == ducks typing badly. It's not pretty. Use === unless you explicitly don't want to check type.

Comment: @DavidBarker Or put constant on the left side :)